# Making disk partitions

Tags: command-line, partitioning

How can I make an extended disk partition that takes up the rest of the space on my vm, through the command line?

Comment: Please explain: you need a partitioning program that run in text mode like cfdisk, fdisk, parted, or you need to create partitions interactively by console commands?

Answer (score 1):

Use program `cfdisk` to create logical partitions, extended partition containing them will be added automatically. The `cfdisk` program is quite easy to use.

Comment: what would be an example of using cfdisk for making the extended partition? would it be cfdisk extended?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use `fdisk [device]`. It's a dialogue-based command-line partition manager. If you type `m` as a command it will show you all available commands with a short description. To create an extended partition:

1. Add a `n`ew partition.
2. Select `e`xtended partition type.
3. If multiple primary slots are free, select one (`1`–`4`).
4. Select the first and last sector. Since you want the whole remainder of the free space to be part of the new partition, the default values will do. To that purpose leave the dialogue responses empty.
5. Optionally `p`rint the resulting partition table before committing it to disk.
6. `w` the new partition table to disk and exit; or `q`uit without saving.
7. Instruct the kernel to pick up the changes with `partprobe [device]` or reboot.

A good advice before every change to a partition table is to create a backup, in case you make a mistake and need to restore the previous state. Create a backup *on a different drive*:

```
sfdisk -d [device] > [backup file]
```

To restore use:

```
sfdisk [device] < [backup file]
```